# Embedded Payments IPN

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have an adaptive payment processed with embedded payments. Everything works fine (the purchase gets processed), but my IPN listener is never notified. I have used the IPN testing tools PayPal provides and the listener picks up calls from that, but not from the embed payment.

This is the info being sent in the paykey:

```php
$bodyparams = array (
 "requestEnvelope.errorLanguage" => \"en_US",         
 "actionType" => "PAY",   
 "cancelUrl" => "http://mysite.com/cancel",       
 "returnUrl" => "http://mysite.com/buying",       
 "currencyCode" => "USD",          
 "paymentType" => "DIGITALGOODS",     
 "ipnNotificationUrl" => 'http://mysite.com/listener.php',    
 "trackingId" => $rows['key'],    
 "memo" => 'You are buying ' . $title . ' from ' . $paypal . '',
 "receiverList.receiver.email" => $paypal,             
 "receiverList.receiver.amount" => $price
);
```

And this is my listener code (taken from the PayPal website):

```php
<?php
  $req = 'cmd=' . urlencode('_notify-validate');

  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
  }

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com'));
  $res = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
  $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
  $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
  $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
  $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
  $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
  $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
  $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

  if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    $myFile = "log.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = "logged ' . $txn_id . '\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
  }
  else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
  }
?>
```

Again, the PayPal IPN testing tool proves that the listener works, but then why does the actual payment not notify the listener?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not using the sandbox URL in the live code.

If you are not go to PayPal login then go to History > IPN History

To see where the IPN have been sent to.

Click on the message id.

Check the Notification URL check that the HTTP response code is 200 and finally check that the  IPN Message contains all the parameters you expect it to.

If you go back to the IPN History screen you can re send the IPN if required.

Comment: The HTTP response code is 200 and the IPN message looks all good. The IPN notification url in it is the same 


    &ipn_notification_url=mysite.com/listener.php